# hough circle opencv iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, detection

I am totally new in OpenCV and Xcode.

I'm trying to find some traffic sign by using colour and hough circle detection. This is what I have done so far:

```
cv::cvtColor(cvImage, cvGrayImage, CV_RGB2HSV);
cv::Mat cvThresh;
cv::inRange(cvGrayImage,cv::Scalar(170,160,10),cv::Scalar(180,255,256),cvThresh);
//cv::dilate(cvThresh,cvThresh, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1,-1),2,1,1);
cv::GaussianBlur(cvThresh, cvThresh, cv::Size(9,9), 2,2);

cv::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
cv::HoughCircles(cvThresh, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,cvThresh.rows/4,200,30);
// NSLog(@"Circles: %ld", circles.size());

for(size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++)
{
    cv::Point center((cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][2])));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    cv::circle(cvImage, center, 3, cv::Scalar(255,0,0), -1, 8, 0);
    cv::circle(cvImage, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0,0,255),3,8,0);
}
```

This is my result, but I have no idea anymore..
Any idea or advice or sample code would be appreciated.

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks for edited tracer..by the way,  any idea why it is not detect the correct circle..i succeed using the same method in opencv windows..thats why iam confused

Answer (score 1):

If you have an idea what size circles you are looking for, then it would be best to set `min_radius` and `max_radius` accordingly. Otherwise, it will return anything circular of any size.

Parameters 1 and 2 don't affect accuracy as such, more reliability.

- Param 1 will set the sensitivity; how strong the edges of the circles need to be. Too high and it won't detect anything, too low and it will find too much clutter.
- Param 2 will set how many edge points it needs to find to declare that it's found a circle. Again, too high will detect nothing, too low will declare anything to be a circle. The ideal value of param 2 will be related to the circumference of the circles.